# Multiplying preprocessor constants in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, ios, llvm, xcode4.3, llvm-clang

Suppose I have the following preprocessor definition

`#define MYNUMBER 10f;`

I would then like to use it in my code as follows:

```
float someResult = MYNUMBER * 3;
```

When I do this, Xcode thinks that I am trying to use `*` as a unary pointer mark instead of multiplication sign, and causes an error. What is the correct method of defining such a constant and using it in a multiplicative expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't have a semicolon after your #define. It things MYNUMBER is "10f;".